# При этом() даже если

Tags: пунктуация

Отцом семейства считался старший член династии. Ему предоставлялись абсолютные права в рамках своей семьи. Здесь он был и верховным жрецом, и обвинителем, и судьёй, и палачом, если придётся. ***При этом() даже если сыновья уже взрослые и имеют собственные семьи, пока жив их отец, именно он считается главой семьи*.**

Нужна ли запятая после **при этом**?

Comment: Добавлен контекст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трудность в определении того, к чему отнести "**при этом**" (к высказыванию в целом, к основному предложению, к придаточному предложению) и ставить ли запятую в соответствии с выявленным смыслом, связана с *отсутствием контекста*. Вне контекста *нельзя* (как это предложено в одном из ответов) изъять конструкцию "даже... семьи" и переставить её в конец предложения: в частности, повиснет в воздухе местоимение "их" (чей отец?). Можно предположить, что предложению предшестовало нечто приводимое ниже в квадратных скобках (такой контекст представляется наиболее вероятным):

> [Если совместно проживают отец и сыновья, то главой семьи считается
>   отец.] **При этом даже если** сыновья уже взрослые и имеют собственные
>   семьи, пока жив их отец, именно он считается главой семьи.

Основным содержанием высказывания здесь является отрицательная оценка возможной аргументации против уже сформулированного утверждения: **при этом** (= при упомянутом условии совместного проживания сыновей с отцом) **даже если** у сыновей такое-то семейное положение, эта особенность ситуации не изменяет уже сказанного (имеется "освежающее" повторение: отец - глава семьи). Здесь нельзя, изъяв "даже... семьи", отнести "*при этом*"  к "*отец - глава семьи*" (такое утверждение ранее сделано, и потому его повторение лишено смысла), поэтому "*при этом*" относится непосредственно к тому, что начинается с "*даже если...*" и **запятой быть не должно** - независимо от того, включать ли в это "*даже если...*" всю последующую часть предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Нужна обязательно. Только не после "при этом", а перед началом придаточного "даже... семьи".
Дело в том, что здесь невозможно рассматривать "при этом" как союз, относящийся к придаточной части: Попробуйте перенести её в конец - при этом все равно останется в начале предложения. 
Примеры у Sibylla - весьма сомнительны, но там еще можно списать на то, что "при этом даже если" = "даже если при этом", т. е. другую грамматическую роль, "при этом" может относится **только** к придаточной части. В исходном же примере это как минимум поменяет смысл на что-то трудно понимаемое.

Comment: Да, понял. Спасибо, IrinaGL!

Comment: При этом - это присоединительный союз, который относится ко всей сложной конструкции, а не к придаточной части (не надо придаточное никуда переносить). А сложная конструкция - это СПП с неоднородным подчинением двух придаточных. Сомнительный источник - это Нацкорпус  (очень полезная вещь, реальные тексты,  дающие представление о традиции письма, все собственные теоретические выкладки очень полезно проверить на практике)

Comment: http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%F0%E8+%FD%F2%EE%EC+%E4%E0%E6%E5+%E5%F1%EB%E8

Comment: Добавлю еще несколько слов о сложном синтаксическом целом. Сложное предложение может состоять из нескольких простых, но отнюдь не всегда они могут рассматриваться как независимые единицы.  Дело в том, что отдельные предложения могут объединяться в БЛОКИ,  то есть более крупные единицы, которые как-то соотносятся друг с другом. и тогда перестановка простых предложений возможна только внутри блока. В приведенном примере такой блок составляют три предложения, и к нему (а не к придаточному) относится присоединительный союз.

Answer (score 1):

**При этом даже если** сыновья уже взрослые и имеют собственные семьи, пока жив их отец, именно он считается главой семьи.

При этом (присоединительный союз/союзный аналог) и усилительная частица ДАЖЕ относятся к союзу ЕСЛИ, запятая не ставится. (Здесь следует  учитывать сложный состав всего предложения).

Примеры: **При этом даже если** банки и держат какие-то избытки ликвидности, как показывает практика, от набега вкладчиков их это не спасает. [Дмитрий Яковенко. Пессимизм с легким привкусом паники // «Эксперт», 2014]. **При этом даже если** вы никогда не востребуете золото в физическом виде, вы все равно будете его полноправным владельцем. [Новости СБСАГРО (1997) // «Столица», 1997.07.29]

В более простых конструкциях  присоединительный союз может относиться к главному предложению (авторское решение): **При этом,** даже если совсем не держать конец веревки рукой, какое-то минимальное трение веревки о ФСУ остается. [Константин Серафимов. Экспедиция во мрак (1978-1996) // , 1994]